# Convert deeply nested XML file to a flat Data Frame

Tags: python, dataframe

I would like to convert a nested XML file to a Python data frame. The structure of the file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<compound>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <creation_date>2020-03-18 23:21:22 UTC</creation_date>
  <update_date>2020-09-11 20:08:57 UTC</update_date>
  <accession>CDB006137</accession>
  <secondary_accessions>
  </secondary_accessions>
  <name>Choline</name>
  <description>Choline, also known as bilineurine, is an organic compound containing a N, N, N-trimethylethanolammonium cation.</description>
  <synonyms>
    <synonym>Bilineurine</synonym>
    <synonym>CHOLINE ion</synonym>
    <synonym>N,N,N-Trimethylethanol-ammonium</synonym>
  </synonyms>
  <taxonomy>
    <description> belongs to the class of organic compounds known as cholines. These are organic compounds containing a N,N,N-trimethylethanolammonium cation.</description>
    <direct_parent>Cholines</direct_parent>
    <kingdom>Organic compounds</kingdom>
    <super_class>Organic nitrogen compounds</super_class>
    <class>Organonitrogen compounds</class>
    <alternative_parents>
      <alternative_parent>1,2-aminoalcohols</alternative_parent>
      <alternative_parent>Hydrocarbon derivatives</alternative_parent>
      <alternative_parent>Organic cations</alternative_parent>
    </alternative_parents>
    <substituents>
      <substituent>1,2-aminoalcohol</substituent>
      <substituent>Alcohol</substituent>
      <substituent>Aliphatic acyclic compound</substituent>
    </substituents>
    <external_descriptors>
      <external_descriptor>Pesticides</external_descriptor>
      <external_descriptor>a small molecule</external_descriptor>
      <external_descriptor>cholines</external_descriptor>
    </external_descriptors>
  </taxonomy>
</compound>
```

I am new to Python and couldn't figure out how to convert this XML structure to a flat dataframe, therefore I am seeking your very much appreciated help.

Thank you in advance.
Cheers.

Comment: try lxml or pandas-read-xml libraries

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there dataframe you expect?